# Como registrar variáveis deste array?

Tags: php, web-service

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que usa um web-service para recuperar os dados necessários a sua alimentação, no segmento de imobiliária. Eu estou aprendendo PHP e tenho muitos problemas no aprendizado de arrays. Voces poderiam me mostrar como poderia recuperar dados específicos deste array: http://axitech.com.br/vista ...

Meu `print_r` está retornando todos os registros consultados, gostaria de poder guardar `CATEGORIA` `BAIRRO` `VALOR` dentro de 3 variáveis diferentes para poder usá-los posteriormente. Eu imagino que neste caso temos um array bidimensional, é isso?

**Evolução:**

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($res[523]['Data cadastro']); echo '</pre>';
```

Com este código eu consigo retornar uma dado especifico de um registro especifico. Mas e se eu quisesse retornar um dados específico de todos os elementos? Tentei o primeiro indice vazio pensando que isso me retornaria a Data cadastro de todos os registros SEM sucesso:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($res[]['Data cadastro']); echo '</pre>';
```

Este é o código completo do meu script:

```
<?php

$array = array(
        'key' => '',
        'module' =>'imoveis',
        'method' => 'busca_imoveis',
        'field' => array(
            'DATA'          => 'Data cadastro',
            'CODIGO'        => 'Codigo',
            'CATEGORIA'     => 'Categoria',
            'UF'            => 'UF',
            'CIDADE'        => 'Cidade',
            'BAIRRO'        => 'Bairro',
            'ENDERECO'      => 'Endereco',
            'NUMERO'        => 'Numero',
            'VLR_VENDA'     => 'Valor',
            'DORMITORIO'    => 'Dormitorios',
            'URL_FOTO'      => 'Url',
            'IMAGEM_G'      => 'Foto'
     ),
        'filter' => array(
            'CONDICAO' => 'VLR_VENDA > 0'
    )
);

$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
        'uri'       => 'http://soap.imo.bi/',
        'location'  => 'http://soap.imo.bi/soap.dll',
        'trace'     => 'trace'
));

$array['order'] = array('VLR_VENDA' => 'DESC');
//$array['limit'] = '0, 10';
$res = $client->get($array);

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: No caso você precisa pergar esses 3 campos de um item só ou de todos do array? ja tentou um `foreach`?

Comment: Esse `print_r($res)` está me retornado todos os itens do `array` com todas suas características conforme mostra o link http://axitech.com.br/vista/index.php. Eu quero desmembrar este `array` para conseguir fazer o que quiser destes dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para pegar um ítem de uma array multidimensional, basta usar mais de um índice.

Exemplos:

```
$teste1 = $array[0]['subitem']; 
$teste2 = $array['item']['subitem'];
```

Notar uso correto de maiúsculas e minúsculas quando se tratar de chave => valor.

> **EDIT:** Conforme atualização da pergunta:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count( $res ); ++$i ) {
    print $res[$i]['Data cadastro'];
 }
```

Comment: Você me deu uma grande ajuda e me mostrou as principais requisições deste sistema que vou desenvolver. Muito obrigado. Se pudesse te daria 500 pontos. rsrs

Comment: @MarcosViniciusNasc.Pereira não precisa exagerar, o "accept" que vc deu ali do lado já é mais do que suficiente, :) - Mas recomendo você fazer mais testes com o básico da linguagem pra pegar o jeitão dela com mais facilidade.