# Agenda de compromissos usando fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NAMED)

Tags: php, pdo, fetchall

Estou usando o fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NAMED) para pegar os registros do meu banco de dados.

recebi o seguinte array

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
              [idAgenda] => 2 
              [dataAgenda] => 1996-02-14 
              [localAgenda] => teste 
              [cidadeAgenda] => São Paulo 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
              [idAgenda] => 1 
              [dataAgenda] => 1996-02-14 
              [localAgenda] => teste2 
              [cidadeAgenda] => Santos 
        ) 
 )
```

Queria saber como eu pego os dados separadamente desse array?

Comment: Eu faria um foreach() para buscar estes valores da array()

Comment: Sim, mas não sei como acessar os elementos [idAgenda],[dataAgenda]... estava tentando algo assim: $list([0] => ($list['idAgenda'])); o array esta na  variável list

Comment: Você pode tentar fazer assim oh: foreach($arr as $valor){
 $idAgenda = $valor["idAgenda"];
 echo $idAgenda;
}

Comment: Acho que o que você perguntou é o que eu já respondi aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31627/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa noite,

Segue um exemplo de como você resgatará os valores.

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    //$value se tornará um array
    $a = $value["item"];
}
```

Está aí fera!

Comment: Isso ai, valeu, bem mais simples do que pensava.

Answer (score 3):

Boa noite,
Então há varias maneiras de resgatar essas informações a que recomendo é o foreach. Porém vou deixar os dois exemplos.

> Exemplo com foreach

```
<?php

//... daqui para trás é o seu código
$dados = $dbh->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);

foreach($dados as $dado) {
    echo $dado['idAgenda'] . '<br />';
    echo $dado['dataAgenda'] . '<br />';
}
```

> Exemplo com FOR

```
<?php

//... daqui para trás é o seu código
$dados = $dbh->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);
$quantidadeReg = count($dados);
for($i = 0; $i < $quantidadeReg; $i++) {
    echo $dados[$i]['idAgenda'] . '<br />';
    echo $dados[$i]['dataAgenda'] . '<br />';
}
```